# Prepaid VISA Debit Card declined on Amazon.com

Tags: banking, debit-card, visa, ecommerce

So I tried to make a purchase on Amazon.com using my Prepaid Visa **Debit** Card but it was declined, they said:

> We have canceled your recent Amazon.com order(s) because we are unable
>   to charge your credit card.

I know that my card works online because I have made payments in the past including on Google Play. And the balance is there as well.

I contacted the bank (UBL - Pakistan) and they said that everything was working OK at their end and that the card should work.

So anyone has any idea where is the problem and why am I unable to make the payment?

Comment: Contact an Amazon.com representative.

Comment: I did. They said they don't know why my card is being declined etc. So I guess that was an exercise in futility!

Comment: Prepaids are allowed to decline requests from specific places if they feel like it, I learned to my annoyance a couple months ago, when I was trying to answer the same question using a prepaid visa to purchase something through paypal. The response I got back eventually was that they just block all paypal transactions, because it's too easy to just convert to cash that way, which they want to forbid. Not saying that *is* the issue, but it could be. (i.e. I wouldn't contact Amazon, I'd contact whoever maintains the prepaid card, and say what specific transaction you were trying to make.)

Comment: @neminem - "too easy to just convert to cash that way". Perhaps it is just a misunderstanding on their part on how PayPal works. When you reverse a transaction (refund) on PayPal, the funds go back to the card that was used for the original transaction... I don't think there is any way to convert it to a cash refund.

Answer (score 2):

Usually there are two verification steps:

- the name on the card
- the billing address associated with the card

that fail in the case of prepaid cards. Here are some possible solutions:

- Register the card online
- Assign a name and address to it

**References**

- [How to use a no name prepaid Master Card for online purchase - Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-use-a-no-name-prepaid-Master-Card-for-online-purchase)
- [Gift Card Frequently Asked Questions (FAQs) | GiftCards.com](https://www.giftcards.com/faq)